# Google AdSense CSE vs. Custom Search - which code to use?

Tags: adsense, google-custom-search

I created a Custom Search Engine in Google AdSense. Then I went to the Google CSE page, where I customized the search engine.

On the AdSense dashboard I cannot cusomize the searchbox and the results layout as much as I would like. On the CSE dashboard I can do it.
E. g.: on the CSE dashboard I can set the results to be full width on the AdSense dashboard I only can set them to be displayed in an iframe which is at least 800px wide.

So I have two code snippets:

1. One I can generate on the AdSense dashboard
2. One I can generate on the CSE dashboard

But now I don't really know, which code to use in order to

- get the money in AdSense
- not to be banned from AdSense

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most up-to-date code snippet is from the CSE dashboard. The one included in Adsense panel is obsolete and will go away at some point.

To make sure you make money with Adsense on your CSE, both Adsense and CSE need to belong to the same owner (the same account). Then in the Make money tab make sure that "Search Engine Monetization" is on. This should be sufficient to make your CSE work with adsense.

To not be banned from Adsense, make sure you follow the Adsense Publisher Guidelines:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en-GB

Hope this helps!